# check if list contains item in Helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a chart that I want to deploy if a certain value is in a list of values.
I've tried the following

```
{{if .Release.Namespace in .Values.Namespaces }}
   <chart goes here>
{{ end }}
```

where the values file used contains the following

```
Namespaces:
  -value1
  -value2
```

but i get an error `function "in" not defined`

Searching the interwebs I've been unable to find what the proper syntax is for checking if a value exists in a list in helm.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the [`has` function](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/lists.html) from the [sprig functions library](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/) which is used by Helm. Please note however that [there's an issue with the documentation of the function](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/issues/116) (the order of the parameters is wrong). In your case should be something like this:

```
{{if has .Release.Namespace .Values.Namespaces }}
   <chart goes here>
{{ end }}
```

Comment: If I am looping over say, .Values.Namespaces can I do something like if my current iteration is "prod" then do X, else do Y. ?